# Resolve maven repo group from incomplete APK reference

Tags: android, maven, apk

I'm working on analyzing APKs to detect third-party libraries.  I've developed some heuristics from scanning the APK to identify possible references.  That's not what this question is about but just providing some background.  Once I identify a possible library reference, I want to cross check it against the maven repo (https://repo1.maven.org) to verify and grab additional details.  But here is where I am stuck.

For sake of argument, let's say I have an APK that references the following:

```
com.tbuonomo.viewpagerdotsindicator
```

Now, if you search for this on mvnrepository.com (https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=com.tbuonomo.viewpagerdotsindicator) nothing comes up however searching for `com.tbuonomo` populates a number of results to include both packages and groups.

The actual repo for `viewpagerdotsindicator` is located here (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.tbuonomo.andrui/viewpagerdotsindicator).  As you can see, this has the additional `andrui` on the groupId and the `com.tbuonomo.andrui` itself is marked as a group in the search results page from above.

The problem is though, I can't find any reference to this via the maven API (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/tbuonomo/) and the APK itself has no reference to `andrui` so I have no way to directly query for `com.tbuonomo.andrui/viewpagerdotsindicator`

So there are a couple of things that I clearly don't understand about maven naming the main one being why `andrui` is not listed under the `com/tbuonomo/` path in the repo?  I know it is marked as a group but I'm not entirely clear what that means nor how to resolve groups in maven so that I can do some fuzzy searching to positively identify the original reference.

Comment: That's more or less what I'm working towards but it still doesn't explain why that 'andrui' name is not part of the group structure given that it is published to maven. I can find it through their search function but cannot navigate to it through their API listing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maven groupId and artifactId are simply chosen names. maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html If they are identical or similar to used package names this is simply coincidence as usually developers use a chosen name on package and e.g. or artifactId level. If you want to identify Maven artifacts by a contained class you need a search engine that has indexed Maven artifacts and that allows you to query the artifact based on a file or package name.

I don't know if such a search service exists, if not build your own by downloading all artifacts and index them.

And if you want to download the artifact you have to consider that there are a lot of other repositories than Maven Central. Only artifacts hosted on Maven central can be found on the server https://repo1.maven.org/maven2.

The artifact `com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator` is only hosted on JCenter:

[image]

Comment: Ah!  I assumed that because JCenter is deprecated that packages would all be moved over to maven.  Thanks for pointing out that's not the case.  Should have looked more closely.